# ConcurrentModificationException while removing duplicates in collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a function to remove the duplicates in a collection.

```
/** Remove the duplicates **/
private List<Topic> removeDuplicateEntries(List<Topic> mlist) {

    List<Topic> allEvents = mlist;
    List<Topic> noRepeat = new ArrayList<Topic>();

    for (Topic event : allEvents) {
          boolean isFound = false;
          // check if the event name exists in noRepeat
          for (Topic e : noRepeat) {
                if (e.getUserId().equals(event.getUserId())){
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
           }
           if (!isFound) noRepeat.add(event);
    }

    return noRepeat;
}
```

Whats happening is sometimes I get the error

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
   at com.sttarter.communicator.CommunicatorDBHelper$1.run(CommunicatorDBHelper.java:54)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: use an `Iterator` instead of classic for loop

Comment: dont use for each loop, use fori(classic for(int i=0;i<n;i++)) loop,

Comment: Neither will help if another thread changes the list concurrently. The code is fine as it is except for synchronization.

Comment: there is another thread that is accessing and modifying `mlist`

Comment: why not `Set<Topic> noRepeat = new HashSet<>(mlist);`

Comment: Don't use a loop. Add `mlist` to a `Set` to remove duplicates. `Set<Topic> result = new HashSet<>(mlst) `.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your code, but I think that the `List` you're given as a parameter is being modified in another thread somewhere. Consider making a copy of it before iterating through it.